# Can't add server(Atlas Cluster) in Mongo Explorer

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, explorer, mongodb-atlas

How can I add and connect to this **Atlas Cluster** from **Mongo Explorer**?:

```
mongo "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl -u m121 -p aggregations --norc
```

PS: I need to add and run this from [Mongo Explorer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7141-mongo-plugin) (Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) not from shell.

github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea

Comment: hi @Yellowfun, I have added the valid connection string to connect to your mongodb deployments as answer. However, it is not recommended to share your DB credentials in the community. Please change the username and passwords of this deployment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a new server as on the image:

[image]

- Server url: `cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017`
- SSL: checked
- User Database: `aggregations`

Then go to Authentication tab and set credentials:

[image]

- Username: `m121`
- Password: `aggregations`
- Auth. database: `admin`
- Auth. mechanism: `SCRAM-SHA-1`

Comment: I've tested out and it is working! Thank you very much! @Alex Blex

Comment: Hey @Yellowfun, you forgot to reset the password. It is violation of [Atlas' T&C](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-management-service-terms-and-conditions). Please do it now, even if you have nothing to hide there. Your cluster is wide open to anyone in the internet - it can be misused, and you are the one to blame: *You are responsible for all activities that occur under your account, regardless of whether undertaken by you*

Answer (score 1):

@Yellowfun:
Try this with mongo shell:

```
mongo --host "mongodb://m121:aggregations@cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017/aggregations?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true&authSource=admin
```

- Server url: `mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jxeqq.mongodb.net:27017?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0`
- Select SSL connection
- In Authentication settings:

  - Username: `m121`
  - Password: `aggregations`
  - Auth.database: admin
  - Authe mechanism: Default
- User database: aggregations

Comment: Hi @Astro! I need to add and run this from Mongo Explorer (Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) not from shell. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7141-mongo-plugin

Comment: Are you able to open a window in intellij from Mongo explorer to 'Add a mongo Server' ?

Comment: Updated answer for Mongo Explorer and fields to be added in Add a mongo server. Check if that helps

Comment: Thank you! But Connectoin Test Failed - For input string: "//cluster0-shard-00-00-jxeqq.mongodb.net"

Comment: are you using same mongo shell version as that of your server: 3.6.5 ?

Comment: My MongoDB shell is v3.6.4

Comment: But it's working from cmd shell (with v3.6.4 ) why it's not working from plugin?

Comment: not sure if this is issue with connector. You can check if there are any know issue noted or you can create one.

Comment: 3.6.4 should be good enough. You can get it from here: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?#community and set path

Comment: I've also created here an issue https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/215 but no one is answering. I think it is not support the clusters. @Astro

Comment: Maybe you know some good shell for mongoDB maybe even with integration with IntelliJ IDEA? @ Astro

Comment: I would recommend using mongo shell if you want to interact with Altas cluster. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think this can help you (use in in Mongo Shell)

mongo "mongodb://username:password@cluster-shard-00-00-6666.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-01-6666.mongodb.net:27017,cluster-shard-00-02-6666.mongodb.net:27017/databaseName?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaName&authSource=admin"

Comment: https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea   Mongo Explorer is a Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA